# Dataweave "contains" returns false with "keysOf" output even though the key is contained

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I'm facing towards a misbehavior of the function [keysOf](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.5/dw-core-functions-keysof) combined with the method [contains](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.5/dw-core-functions-contains).

Given an object like:

```
    {
     "keyA":1,
     "keyB":2
    }
```

And given the Dataweave script like:

```
keysOf(payload) contains "keyA"
```

I'm expecting to have ***true*** as outcome, but it returns ***false***.

The ***keysOf*** function returns an array containing the keys of the previously mentioned object, like so:

```
[
 "keyA",
 "keyB"
]
```

Which, if used in the following script, it returns the ***true*** expected outcome:

```
[ "keyA", "keyB" ]  contains "keyA"
```

The workaround I tried to implement, storing the ***keysOf*** outcome into a variable, doesn't work either:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var keysOfPayload=keysOf(payload)
---
keysOfPayload contains "keyA"
```

The goal of this question, is not to find a workaround, for instance using the [question mark selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-selectors) against the key, works as expected:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var object= {"keyA":1,"KeyB":2}
---
object.keyA?
```

Rather, I'm willing to understand why the combination of ***keysOf*** and ***contains*** is not effective as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [keysOf()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.5/dw-core-functions-keysof) works exactly as expected. The problems is a common misconception of how it works. It returns an array of the keys with the `Key` type. When you try to compare it to a `String` the comparison returns false correctly. It may be not obvious because when a `Key` is output to an output format it seems to be automatically converted to `String` so it is no visible. It is also a common issue when using `mapObject()` and comparing the key parameter to a `String` directly.

To make this work you need to do one of two things:

1. **Recommended** use the functions [namesOf()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.5/dw-core-functions-namesof) instead: `namesOf(a) contains "keyA"`. Note that `namesOf()` converts the keys to strings and returns an array of Strings.
2. Convert the `String` to a `Key` explicitly before using: `keysOf(a) contains ("keyA" as Key)`.